# Visual Studio files not displaying in Open Project for VB.Net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a project that I built on my work computer. I installed VS 2015 on my home computer and I cannot open the project files on the home computer via the Open Project/Solution option in VS since it does not display any files. In other words the files are not showing in the Open Project dialog box.
What am I doing wrong or what should I do different? 
[Open Project Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMuJG.png)

Comment: `Open Project` loads *projects*, ie files with the `.sln` extension. How *did* you build your project if you didn't use a solution file? If you did, are you sure you are looking in the correct folder?

Comment: Don't click on sln instead double click on proj file.  You should get a message to save a new sln file.  Then the sln file will also work.

Comment: All of the files for the project have an XML extension. I have two different projects and both have the XML extensions. I don't recall seeing this before.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out that the problem is the company I worked for encrypts files that get copied to an external drive without the user being able to tell that they are encrypted until the user logs into an outside network. So it appends and XML extension onto each file which is how I figured out that the files were encrypted.